# How to change states of all checkboxes (in all pages) when clicked selectAll checkbox [using jQuery datatable]

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to modify a jQuery dataTable by adding checkbox column. My table consist of multiple pages. I would like to add a select all checkbox and when I click it, it needs to selects all the checkboxes in all pages. My problem is that, currently it only selects the checkboxes on the current page.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="results_table">

  <h3>Results</h3>
        <div>
        <h5 style="float:left;">Results - Table</h5>
        <button id="download-json" class="btn" style="float:right;"><i class="icon-download"></i> Get JSON</button>
        <button id="download-csv" class="btn" style="float:right;"><i class="icon-download"></i> Get CSV</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
        <div id="results_container">

        <p>Execute a query first!</p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you fine, you need to store the checkbox state to apply when another page loads (or have you got a SPI web?)

You can store in `sessionStorage` with Javascript:

```
var storage = window.sessionStorage; // initialize storage object

$('input[type="checkbox"][name="selectAll"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
            storage.setItem("checkALL", true); // save state
        });
    }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;  
            storage.setItem("checkALL", false);  //save state
        });
    }
});
```

When you load another page, you can handle in load event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var storage = window.sessionStorage;
     $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
         $(this).prop('checked', storage.getItem("checkALL")); // set state
     });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Unfortunatelly, although I replaced my .click function with yours and add .ready() function, my problem did not solve. Do I need to change something else too ? @Marcos_Pérez_Gude

Comment: Where do you are inserting `ready` function? Note that this piece of code may loads when a new page is loaded (link, refresh, etc). Your console throughs any errors? Please, be more specific in order to help you. I am only speculating with your problem. The code in my answer must to work

Comment: I've added ready function just under the .click function . Is it wrong ?By the way I do not get any error or warning

Comment: So, you paginate with ajax? OR you are loading a new page? ready function only works for a new page. If you are paginating by ajax technology, you must to add after load content data

Comment: Please, be more specific. You need to tell us every details, if not we can't help you. I give you a valid answer, but maybe you need to adapt to your project.

Comment: I think that you are using some component like `jqGrid` or `jquery datatables`. Check this and the answer will be totally different (it's the reason why I tell you be more specific ;))

Comment: I'm using jquery datatables @Marcos Pérez Gude

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88454/discussion-between-zwlayer-and-marcos-perez-gude).